# Using a portfolio_category slug in wordpress URL

Tags: categories, urls, slug

I won't lie - I don't know php but I enjoy digging around trying to find ways to customize themes so that they behave how I want them to. Any help would be very much appreciated.

What I am trying to do:

There is a section in a wordpress theme I am using which allows you to publish portfolios.

The URL for any portfolio page would be:

**mysite.com/portfolio/example-portfolio**

When creating a new portfolio, you are given the option to assign a portfolio category, much in the same way as when you create a new post.

I would like to be able to have my portfolio URL's appear like this:

**mysite.com/portfolio-category/example-portfolio**

I have highlighted an area of code I suspect might be editable to allow for this, but that is where my adventure sadly ends :(

Here is the code:

```
function mysite_post_types() {
    register_post_type('portfolio', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x('Portfolios', 'post type general name', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type singular name', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'new_item' => __('New Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'view_item' => __('View Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'search_items' => __('Search Portfolios', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'not_found' =>  __('No portfolios found', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolios found in Trash', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ),
        'singular_label' => __('Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'products' ),
```

I have worked out how to change 'mysite.com/**portfolio**/example-portfolio' to 'mysite.com/**products**/example-portfolio' (on the last line in the example) but I don't want to stop there!

Since you can categorize the portfolios I would like to take advantage of this in the URLs which are generated.

This is surely possible with not too much work involved, and I would be very grateful if somebody with more php knowledge than myself (which doesn't take much!) could let me lean on them for a solution

thanks

Answer (score 3):

add

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio-categories'),
```

but be sure to remove (not sure why that's there, it tries hides the slug yet tries to rename it to "products" at the same time?):

```
'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'products' ),
```

So it looks like this:

```
function mysite_post_types() {
register_post_type('portfolio', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x('Portfolios', 'post type general name', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type singular name', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'search_items' => __('Search Portfolios', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'not_found' =>  __('No portfolios found', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolios found in Trash', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ), 
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ),
    'singular_label' => __('Portfolio', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio-categories')
     )
    );
```

just make sure the register_post_type closes out correctly, the code you posted ends in the middle of the array.  i closed it for you but i'm not sure if you left anything out.  some examples here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do this with Permalink?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks